# Error: package com.dm.zbar.android.scanner does not exist?

Tags: java, android

I've imported the lib to my project and I've configured the settings build.gradle.  I can use any class that library in my project but when I tried execute my project, this error occurred.
I've already include Zbar lib in settings.grandle.
Can you help me?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 18
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/zbar.jar')}
```

.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.paulohenrique.digitalsetqrcode"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 18
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])}
```

Comment: I've already included zbar lib in settings.grandle

Comment: Right-click that library (jar) and select Add as Library in Android Studio? - Assuming you have the jar library inside a libs folder

Comment: I imported the folder not the jar. I can use the library but when I executed the project occurred the error